# Can a "safe delete" be implemented for an IMAP server in Maildir mode?

Tags: linux, email, delete

I'd like to make sure a message, when deleted from an IMAP account (say on a locally installed server that I would manage) is safe deleted, i.e. filled with random data *before* being actually deleted. What I have in mind is a mail service installed on a Linux machine, which provides IMAP access.

Can that be implemented? (Or is it already?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically it *can* be implemented (I am not aware of any current implementation), however it would be a moot point.

You are trying to provide a "secure wipe" function to ensure confidentiality of email messages; however, the message has already transited in plaintext through multiple mailservers from the sender to its final destination. Hence, its confidentiality cannot be ensured. It's like trying to strengthen a chain by reinforcing just one of its links.

If the email messages are instead encrypted end-to-end, there's no need for a "secure wipe" function.

Comment: You have a point about this feature being moot. However the current regulations here in Europe will tend to have companies make sure personal data actually *are* deleted, especially if such a can feature be enforced. The GDPR, for instance (since this is the context I had in mind for my question) will apply to *all* European companies which will have personal data stored either transient or permanent. The safe deletion therefore might apply to all nodes through which a message has passed. This might be true when a user requests their personal data be erased, for example.

Comment: The purpose here is not confidentiality rather than a stricter implementation of the right to be forgotten, which the EU voted a few years ago. So in this case, tools or programs that *undelete* files would be prohibited if run for recovering personal data of users who requested their deletion.

Comment: I understand.  In this case you should check with a lawyer.  I do not know whether the EU regulations mandate that user data is simply "deleted" or "securely wiped out so it cannot be retrieved by forensic analysis".